# Get and validate string with pattern for a multiline string 

Tags: php

The string looks like this which is queried from a database:

fname@site.com
Added description.

---

I use this function to validate the email.

```
email_validator($email){
    $pattern = "/^[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\.|\-|_]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+@([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\.|\-]?[a-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,4}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/sm";
    if(preg_match($pattern,$email)){
        $result = 1;
        //$result = $match;
    } else {
        $result = 0;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

A similar function should also return the email address.

How to modify the validation to include the newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the pattern

```
$pattern = "/(.+.@.+\.com)/";
```

Now I can get the email portion and pass it to a validation which is more strict.

Comment: It's worth to note that that works for .com only. The first though might be or-ing TLDs together, but that's an exhaustive list, so I suggest you settle for a word match of a certain length (see TLD max length spec for more info).

Comment: You can  make it for character with two or three letter if you want to. That is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to return the email?

If you call a method with a param (an email in your case), you do not need to get this param in return. You already know it.

Comment: It is comming from a wiki page which is stored in a database. It may be composed of different lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse_thingy($text){
    $temp=str_replace(array(chr(13).chr(10),chr(10)),chr(13),$text);
    $temp=explode(chr(13),$temp,2);
    return array('email'=>$temp[0],'desc'=>$temp[1]);
}
```

Comment: The arrangement of the string is random. It is not really a list. It can be a wiki page.

Comment: Ah, you mean you want to match emails in a block of text?

Comment: Sorry, but I have not been clear that I the string is really like that. But it give me an idea about line feeds and other chr s.